# Crystal Reports: Programmatically setting parameter values in a subreport through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, subreport

When trying to print my Crystal Reports RPT(MainReport) in my CrystalReportViewer1, I don't know how to set the parameter for the Subreport (report1).

I've tried this:

```
Report1.DataDefinition.ParameterFields("@code_machine").CurrentValues.AddValue(3)
```

But it doesn't work, it show me the input box of CrystalReports.

I also tried :

```
Report1.SetParameterValues("@code_machine", 3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MainReport.SetParameterValue("@code_machine", 3, "report1")

Documentation reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20140321115705/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226106(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please expound upon your answer to help future visitors to the site?